# I built the front-end of my MVP. Now, what do I do next?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, backend, mvp

I am stuck on taking the next steps to delve into backend for my first SaaS project.

I have created the front-end and now require the backend and server-side aspects but, as a total beginner, I am lost as to where to go from here. I have looked into AWS, deployment and the related on a fundamental level but am not sure if I am still going in the right direction, and cannot understand half of what I am reading/watching.

Help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to build a backend for web applications, there are some easy to learn web frameworks that I'd suggest.

- Django - Python: https://www.djangoproject.com/
- Node.js - Javascript:    https://nodejs.org/en/
- Ruby on Rails - Ruby: https://rubyonrails.org/

If you come from a frontend background, Node might be your best bet because you may already know JS.  I prefer Django, but all three of these frameworks are very robust and can support a small MVP and scale all the way up to huge deployments.  Good luck.